# Share BlackBerry 3G connection with laptop

Tags: tethering, blackberry

I want to share my BlackBerry's 3G connection with my laptop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called tethering.

There are programs available like [Tether](http://www.tether.com) and [PDANet](http://www.junefabrics.com/blackberry/index.php) that will let you do that.

Comment: thanks a lot! i will try them, i am really newbie with the blackberrys.
if that works, I will update a little later.

Comment: tether works, however i had to configure APN

Comment: I have successfully used Tether for some time now.  I didn't have to configured APN.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can tether a BlackBerry to a Windows machine to use as a 3G modem, using just your BlackBerry's built-in software and the BlackBerry desktop software, no third party software needed.

An old but good guide to this is [Using your 8707g as a 3G modem with your Windows XP laptop (PDF)](http://www.my-blackberryfromo2.com/documents/O2_Blackberry_%208707_Modem_Guide.pdf).

Note that your carrier can disable this tethering feature, if so then 3rd party software is your only option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac or on Windows, the BlackBerry Desktop Software will allow you to tether if your provider allows for that.